# Bodyvertising definition

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Is *bodyvertising* a word that can describe a person who sells his body for advertising purposes? For example with a tattoo or any other method.

Comment: It means whatever the bodyvertiser says it means.

Comment: Wouldn’t it be better as ***bodvertising***??

Comment: This site is devoted to analysing the **established** ways of using English language; it is not the best place evaluating proposed neologisms.

Comment: I searched for bodyvertising, bodvertising, and tattoovertising in Google Ngram, it didn't find any of them. So it's up to you to decide what to call it.

Comment: Bodvetising for sure rolls off the tongue better because it has the same number of syllables as "Advertising" .. but bodyvertising defines exactly body advertising.